# How do I disable copy, paste and select functions in a UIWebView that is showing a PDF file?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiwebview

My app has a UIWebView that is used for showing a PDF file. The file size is less than 1MB but when the user double taps the screen, the app freezes and crashes a few moments later. 
I think that if I disabled the select function, maybe this problem wouldn't occur. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the console output. It looks like you are not handling tap events properly.  You must have those handlers even if you want to ignore tap events (i.e. do nothing and return).

Here's a good overview of what needs to be done:

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks Jacek, but is that really the only possible solution? I think it is a bit complicated to implement. The UIWebView works perfectly fine. The problem happens only when the user holds or double taps it. The app freezes for some seconds and when the PDF is scrolled again it eventually crashes.

Comment: What messages do you see in the Console window after the app crashes?

Comment: If you see 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' anywhere in the output in the Console window then it is clear sign that you **must** implement the missing handlers.

Comment: No messages are displayed after the app crashes. But before the app crashes the Console displays two memory warnings.